# Using gb4e to insert footnote in \gll line

Tags: footnotes, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I am using gb4e for my examples. I can insert footnote in the `\ex` line, like this:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex It's ok\footnote{no problem}.
\end{exe}
```

But I cannot insert footnote in the `\gll` line, like this:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex It's ok.
\gll C'est parfait\footnote{no problem}\\
Ce est parfait\\
\end{exe}
```

When I put the `\footnote{}` in `\gll` line, it does not compile.

How can I insert footnote in the gloss line?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex It's ok.\footnote{no problem}
\gll C'est parfait\footnotemark\\
Ce est parfait\\
\end{exe}
\footnotetext{no problem?}
\end{document}
```