# Capacity Error (with isolated problematic excerpt from code/minimal non-working example)

Tags: errors, footnotes, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I am working on an article in XeLaTeX and I am getting this error: capacity exceeded main memory size=5000000

By moving around \end{document} and by cutting and pasting various parts of the document, I have isolated the problem to the following section.

Could someone point me towards the problem? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I believe this to be the minimum (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex \gll suk hapáng\footnote{corresponds to the proclitic /hap=/} \\
house above \\
\glt 'on top of (a) house'
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex 
\gll yątci kį sukhǫ́\footnote{corresponds to the proclitic /suk=/} wąre \\
stream the over sit.{\Ind} \\
\glt '[It] sits over the stream.'
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex yancámǫntu \\
\gll yancá mǫntu \\
creek in \\
\glt 'in [a] creek'
\end{exe}
\enddocument
```

Comment: The problem appears to be the footnote inside the `exe` environment.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334636/35864 for a workaround

Comment: @moewe Hey, this worked perfectly! If you'll put your answer as an answer I'll be able to mark it as solved :). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Since all the necessary information can be found in the linked Q&A, it might be easier to just mark this question here as a duplicate.